# xCode fails to create a new Core Data Model Version

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5, core-data-migration

I am updating an existing app and wish to create a new Model Version.

Looks like xCode creates a new Model instead of crating a version (See screenshot), This way I can not change the current model, and that looks wrong to me.

[image: xCode navigator]

This is how is  suppose  to look like -

[image: enter code here]

And I don't see the option to change the current version.
Testing on other projects it looks OK so I don't think this is xCode.

Any Idea why can this happen ?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: That's how it would look if you're creating a new version...  Why do you think you can't change the current model?

Comment: Hi @LyndseyScott edited my question to show how it is usually looks like.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. When creating a new data model, did you select the data model then go to Editor > Add Model Version?

Comment: Yes, Did that many times before :(

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note here...

A data model version has the icon - [image: Data Model Version Icon]

A data model version has the extension `.xcdatamodel`.

A data model package displays the icon - [image: Data Model Package Icon]

A data model package has the extension `.xcdatamodeld`. Note the **d** at the end.

A data model package contains all versions of the data model, to enable it to undertake lightweight migration for any previous version of the data model up to and including the latest model version.

---

It appears that you have a model version without the data model package container/wrapper. As I understand the process, your version must be contained within a package.

You may need to complete one of two processes here...

**Process One**

Find the original data model package with extension `.xcdatamodeld`, that includes ALL previous model versions.

If necessary, copy that entire package into your project.

Then prepare the code to undertake a migration to a new data model.

**Process Two**

If you cannot find or do not have access to the original data model package, you may need to rebuild your data model, keeping in mind an existing user's data store.

**"Wildcard" Option**

I have not tried this, but it may be worth attempting to rename your version file name to `jerusalemBiblicalZoo.xcdatamodeld`. Then try @LyndseyScott's suggestion again. This may save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem recently and @andrewbuilder answer give me the hint to achieve it.

Just go to your project navigator and delete the references to both `.xcdatamodel` files. Then, in finder, drag your `.xcdatamodeld` file (package indeed) and drop it in the project navigator. This should take care of your problem.